SvelteKit + Capacitor: Images and Audio Not Loading in iOS Simulator
I'm working on a SvelteKit project with Capacitor to build a mobile app. The app should display images and play audio files. Everything works fine in the browser, but when I run the app in the iOS simulator, the images and audio files do not load. I'm able to see the names of the audio track, go to the next track I have loaded and see the names of the images in the dropdown but no functionality from either.
Project Setup:

SvelteKit: Using @sveltejs/adapter-static
Capacitor: For building the mobile app
Build Tool: Vite

svelte.config.js:
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: 'index.html'
        }),
        prerender: { entries: [] }
    }
};

export default config;

capacitor.config.ts:
import type { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
    appId: 'com.example.app',
    appName: 'player2',
    webDir: 'build'
};

export default config;

src/routes/+layout.js:
export const prerender = 'auto';

Relevant code:
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

    // Audio Context and Nodes
    let audioContext: AudioContext | null = $state(null);
    let gainNode: GainNode | null = $state(null);
    let audioSource: MediaElementAudioSourceNode | null = $state(null);
    let wavesurfer = $state<WaveSurfer | null>(null);

    // Audio Player State
    let audioPlayer = $state<HTMLAudioElement | null>(null);
    let isPlaying = $state(false);
    let currentPlaybackTime = $state('00:00');
    let totalTrackDuration = $state('00:00');
    let isMuted = $state(false);
    let volumeLevel = $state<number>(100);
    let savedVolumeLevel = $state<number>(100);
    let currentTrackPosition = $state(0);
    let seekPosition = $state(0);
    let seekValue = $state(0);
    let isDragging = $state(false);
    let divLoaded = $state(false);
    let currentTrack = $state<string>('');
    let tracks: Object = $state({});
    let songLoaded = $state(false);

    // Image State
    let sortedImages: string[] = $state([]);
    const imageModules = import.meta.glob('../images/*');

    onMount(() => {
        wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
            container: '#waveform',
            waveColor: '#00bcd4',
            progressColor: '#d946ef',
            url: currentTrack,
            barWidth: 1,
            barGap: 0.5,
            barRadius: 1,
            height: 30
        });
        wavesurfer.setVolume(0);
        wavesurfer.on('click', (newTime) => {
            if (audioPlayer) {
                const duration = audioPlayer.duration;
                const newTimeInSeconds = newTime * duration;
                audioPlayer.currentTime = newTimeInSeconds;
            }
        });

        sortedImages = Object.keys(imageModules).sort((a, b) => {
            const nameA = a.split('/images/')[1].toLowerCase();
            const nameB = b.split('/images/')[1].toLowerCase();

            const matchA = nameA.match(/^([a-z]+)-(\d+)/);
            const matchB = nameB.match(/^([a-z]+)-(\d+)/);

            if (matchA && matchB) {
                const prefixCompare = matchA[1].localeCompare(matchB[1]);
                if (prefixCompare !== 0) return prefixCompare;

                return parseInt(matchA[2]) - parseInt(matchB[2]);
            }

            return nameA.localeCompare(nameB);
        });

        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * sortedImages.length);
        selectedImage = `/src${sortedImages[randomIndex].slice(2)}`;

        tracks = import.meta.glob('/src/audio/*');
        const trackKeys = Object.keys(tracks);
        if (trackKeys.length > 0) {
            currentTrack = trackKeys[0];
            if (audioPlayer) {
                audioPlayer.src = currentTrack;
                audioPlayer.addEventListener(
                    'loadedmetadata',
                    () => {
                        if (audioPlayer) {
                            totalTrackDuration = formatSecondsToMinutesSeconds(audioPlayer.duration);
                            songLoaded = true;
                        }
                    },
                    { once: true }
                );
            }
        }
    });

    $effect(() => {
        seekValue = isDragging ? seekPosition : currentTrackPosition;

        if (audioPlayer) {
            setupAudioContext();

            const handleTimeUpdate = () => {
                currentPlaybackTime = formatSecondsToMinutesSeconds(audioPlayer?.currentTime ?? null);
                currentTrackPosition = audioPlayer?.currentTime ?? 0;
                if (wavesurfer) {
                    const progress = audioPlayer ? audioPlayer.currentTime / audioPlayer.duration : 0;
                    wavesurfer.seekTo(progress);
                }
            };

            const handleAudioEnded = () => {
                if (activeRepeat) {
                    if (audioPlayer) {
                        audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
                        audioPlayer.play();
                    }
                    isPlaying = true;
                } else {
                    playNextTrack();
                }
            };

            const handleAudioDuration = () => {
                totalTrackDuration = formatSecondsToMinutesSeconds(audioPlayer?.duration ?? null);
                document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
                    '--spin-duration',
                    $tapeSpeeds.find((speed) => speed.isActive)?.speed + 's'
                );
            };

            handleAudioDuration();

            audioPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', handleTimeUpdate);
            audioPlayer.addEventListener('ended', handleAudioEnded);
            audioPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', handleAudioDuration);

            return () => {
                audioPlayer?.removeEventListener('timeupdate', handleTimeUpdate);
                audioPlayer?.removeEventListener('ended', handleAudioEnded);
                audioPlayer?.removeEventListener('loadedmetadata', handleAudioDuration);
            };
        }
    });
</script>

<img
    src={selectedImage}
    alt="cd canvas"
    class={`max-h-48 max-w-full rounded-full object-contain ${isPlaying ? 'spin-slow' : 'spin-slow paused'}`}
/>

<audio src={currentTrack} bind:this={audioPlayer} controls preload="auto" hidden></audio>

<select name="records" id="record" bind:value={selectedImage}>
    {#each sortedImages as image}
        <option value={`/src${image.slice(2)}`}>
            {image.split('../images/')[1]}
        </option>
    {/each}
</select>

I'm not too familiar with Capacitor outside of the docs and a few reddit suggestions so anything and any help is appreciated!
